# Why is my PyInstaller .exe file marked as a virus

Tags: python, pyinstaller

This has happened several times before. No matter what I put inside of a Python file and use PyInstaller, it will be marked as a virus no matter what place you download it from. I want to be able to have my users download my file, but it will just be marked as a virus. What is going on and is there a way to fix it?

[Example](https://gitlab.com/EvokerKing/pc-stats/-/releases)

Comment: I got this too in the last couple of days. What you are seeing is a false positive from Windows Defender. It *thinks* it has detected the signature of a virus. It's wrong. You may be able to make the problem go away if you temporarily stop specifying `--onefile` which will allow you to carry on until Microsoft fixes the false positive. Or whitelist your executable, since you created it and you know there isn't a virus.

Comment: @BoarGules I normally use a program from PySimpleGUI to run the command. The reason I do this is because I don't know how to add an icon to a .exe when running the command. I guess it puts in `--onefile` for me. So if I can't use that, how do I add an icon?

Comment: Best I can suggest is you try to find out what command line PySimpleGUI is issuing. Does it maybe log it?

Comment: Yes, but it is too fast for me to see what is happening.

Comment: I meant, log it to a file.

Comment: Otherwise, whitelist your project folder. Settings | Virus & threat protection | Manage settings | Exclusions: Add or remove exclusions | Add an exclusion.

Comment: @BoarGules I know I can whitelist it, but as I said, I don't want to have to give everyone the instruction to whitelist a random download. That would seem sketchy. I will try to find a log but I haven't been able to find one yet.

Comment: I think your best move is to raise this as an issue with the `pyinstaller` team. Microsoft won't accept notices of false positives from ordinary users like you and me. I tried it. The reporting page goes into a loop. Maybe the maintainers will have enough clout to get a hearing. But don't bet on it.

Comment: Here's a different approach. I tried Python 3.7 and created a fresh `.exe` in a folder that was not whitelisted. I did not get a "security threat". I did get *Your administrator requires a security scan of this item. The scan could take up to 10 seconds.*   But the program ran after that.

Comment: @BoarGules Okay. I will add it as an issue with pyinstaller. And also, it shouldn't happen when you run it locally normally? It only happens for me if I add it to a website (Personal, GitHub, GitLab, etc.) and then download it from there. It won't finish because it is marked as a virus. See an example [here](https://gblobscdn.gitbook.com/assets%2F-MQMuyNTfBf5ZIPx2kOS%2F-MQY1SsFzSrU3OAwTP3z%2F-MQY1TlcIWHVVhpdEvSF%2Fimage.png?alt=media&token=dd75e123-1ab4-4407-bfbd-7fbad4c86107).

Comment: On my machine the OS quarantines it a few seconds after `pyinstaller` is finished writing it, unless I whitelist the folder.

Answer (score 0):

since there are so many malware developers that use python
they make there python scripts a executable so people don't read the code which causes it to get detected
it could also be getting detected because it drops files when you use --onefile
and my advice is you either downgrade pyinstaller or you convert it to c# or you contact anti virus vendors